# Llamar variable de una clase a otra POO java

Tags: java, poo

Buenas Estoy haciendo un proyecto de POO, y deseo sacar un dato de una clase Empleado, para hacer una comparación en otra clase Salario, ¿esto se puede hacer? ¿o la comparación la debo hacer en el método main directamente ?`import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

```
/**
 *
 * @author Luis Eduardo
 */
public class test {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

       //creacion del objeto P, segmento que craga datos del empleado por pantalla y los muestra por pantalla

      Empleado p = new Empleado ();

      p.setDatos(null, null);
      JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "NOMBRE: "+p.getDatos());
      JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "CARGO: "+p.getCargo());
      // Promedio de comision maxima que es el 15% de su sueldo maximo
      p.setComision();
      JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "SALARIO: "+p.getSalrio());
      JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "COMISION: "+p.getComisionmax());

      // creacion del objeto cuenta ademas de operar los dosdescuenotos disponibles en el programa (descuento prestamo y descuento ahorro)
      Salario liquidacion = new Salario ();

      liquidacion.SetDesceuntos();
      JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "DESCUENTO: "+ liquidacion.getDescuento());

      //Comparacion de valores de comision del mes 
      liquidacion.setComisionReal();

       if (liquidacion.ValorTotalComi > p.valorMaxComision)
       {
           JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"La comision asignada Es mayor a la legal ");
       }
       else
       {
           JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "La comision de este mes es:"+liquidacion.ValorTotalComi);
       }

       liquidacion.setParaficales();
       JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "DESCUENTO PARAFISCALES: "+ liquidacion.GetParafiscales());




    }

}
```

Siguiente clase Empleado:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;



/**
 *
 * @author Luis Eduardo
 */
public class Empleado 
{
    //variable nativas.
    String nombreEmpleado;
    String cargoEmpleado;
    int salarioMensual;
    double valorMaxComision;

    //constructores 
    public Empleado ()
    {
      this.salarioMensual = 0;
      this.valorMaxComision = 0.0;
      this.nombreEmpleado = "";
      this.cargoEmpleado = "";
    }

    public Empleado (String nombreEmpleado,String cargoEmpleado, int salarioMensual,double valorMaxComision)
    {
       this.nombreEmpleado = nombreEmpleado;
       this.cargoEmpleado = cargoEmpleado;
       this.salarioMensual = salarioMensual;
       this.valorMaxComision = valorMaxComision;

    }
    //Metodos

    public void setDatos (String nombreEmpleado,String cargoEmpleado) 
    {
       this.nombreEmpleado = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Por Favor ingrese el nombre del empleado:");
       this.cargoEmpleado = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Por Favor ingrese el cargo del empleado:");
       this.salarioMensual=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Por Favor ingrese el salario del empleado:"));

    }
    public void setComision ()
    {
        this.valorMaxComision = (salarioMensual * 15)/100;
    }
    public String getDatos () 
    {
        return nombreEmpleado;
    }

    public String getCargo ()
    {
        return cargoEmpleado;
    }

    public double getSalrio()
    {
        return salarioMensual;
    }
    public double getComisionmax ()
    {
        return valorMaxComision;
    }


}
```

Clase Salario:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


/**
 *
 * @author Luis Eduardo
 */
public class Salario
{
    //variable nativas.

    int ValorTotalDes;
    int ValorTotalComi;
    int DesParafiscal;
    int prestamoEmpresa;
    int DescuentoAhorro;
    int SalarioMensual;
    int valorParafiscal;
    int salarioNeto ;


    //constructores 

    public Salario ()
    {
      this.ValorTotalDes = 0;
      this.ValorTotalComi = 0;
      this.DesParafiscal =  0;
      this.prestamoEmpresa =0;
      this.DescuentoAhorro =0;
      this.SalarioMensual =0;
      this.valorParafiscal =0;
      this.salarioNeto =0 ;

    }
    public void Salario (int valorTotalDes,int valorTotalComi, int DesParafiscal,int SalarioMensual, int ValorParafiscal, int salarioNeto)
    {
      this.ValorTotalDes = valorTotalDes ;
      this.ValorTotalComi = valorTotalComi;
      this.DesParafiscal = DesParafiscal;
      this.SalarioMensual = SalarioMensual;
      this.valorParafiscal = ValorParafiscal;
      this.salarioNeto = salarioNeto;
    }
    //metodos

    public void SetDesceuntos ()
    {
       this.prestamoEmpresa =  Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Por favor indique el valor del prestamo"));
       this.DescuentoAhorro =  Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Por favor indique el valor para el fonde de ahorro"));

       this.ValorTotalDes = prestamoEmpresa + DescuentoAhorro;
    }

    public int getDescuento ()
    {
        return ValorTotalDes;
    }

    public void setComisionReal ()
    {
        this.ValorTotalComi = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el valor de la comision de este mes"));
    }

    public int getComisionReal()
    {
        return ValorTotalComi;
    }
    public void setParaficales ()
    {
        this.SalarioMensual= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el valor del salario de este mes"));

        valorParafiscal = (SalarioMensual*8)/100;

    }

    public int GetParafiscales ()
    {
        return valorParafiscal;
    }

    public void SetSalarioNeto ()
    {
        this.salarioNeto = SalarioMensual + ValorTotalComi - valorParafiscal - ValorTotalDes;
    }

    public int getSalarioNeto ()
    {
        return salarioNeto;
    }

   }
```

Comment: Podrías enviar el objeto de la clase Empleado como parámetro al constructor de la clase Salario. Si puedes poner algo de código puedo ser más específico con la respuesta.

Comment: Seria de ayuda saber como tienes tus dos clases y tu metodo main.

Comment: Muéstranos el código que tienes para ayudarte correctamente. Lo que dices sí es posible.

Comment: Listo ya puse el código, gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para acceder a las propiedades del objeto, solo debes declararla como estaticas asi podras acceder de otra clase sin tener la instancia.

```
    public class Empleado {
String nombreEmpleado; 
static String variableAComparar;
}

public class OtraClase{
    public void compararAlgo(){
        if(Empleado.variableAcomparar=="algun valor"){
            //true
        }
    }
}
```

Ten en cuenta que la variable a comprar ya debe estar con valor antes de hacer la comparación, si lo haces en el constructor no hay problema.

```
Empleados emp=new Empleados();
emp.elMetodoQueCargaLasVariables();
Otraclase oc=new OtraClase();
oc.compararAlgo();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sí se puede, pero las variables salarioMensualdouble, valorMaxComision deberían estar en Salario, es un problema conceptual que pertenezcan a Empleado.
Como lo estás haciendo tienes que crear una propiedad/variable de tipo Empleado dentro de Salario. Ambas clases deben ser public y todas las variables tener constructor y getters and setters.

```
public class Salario
{
    Empleado empleado1;//el nombre puede ser otro

    //constructors

    public Salario()
    {
    }

    public Salario(Empleado empleado1)
    {
        this.empleado1 = empleado1;
    }

    //get and set

    public Empleado getEmpleado1()
    {
        return this.empleado1;
    }

    public void setEmpleado1(Empleado empleado1)
    {
        this.empleado1 = empleado1;
    }

    /*  método personalizado
     *  X viene de la clase Empleado
     *  */

    public void comparar()
    {
        int y=1;
        if (getEmpleado1().getX()==y)
        {
            //acción
        }
    }
}

public class Empleado
{
    private int x;

    //constructors
    public Empleado()
    {
    }

    public Empleado(int x)
    {
        this.x = x;
    }

    //get and set
    public int getX()
    {
        return this.x;
    }

    public void setX(int x)
    {
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Amablemente desaconsejo usar static en este caso, como propone @Aquiles Perez, static es para propiedades como constantes.

Answer (score 0):

agrega a `public class Salario`, modificalo para ser una **subclase de Empleado**

```
public class Salario extends Empleado{...}
```

ya con eso cualquier variable de **Empleado** se puede transferir de forma transparente a **Salario**